# Embedded Linux kernel debug

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, kgdb

I am working on a proprietary board at my workplace. Linux image (built from yocto) is copied into and getting booted from eMMC. Facing some issues in kernel startup. Are there any ways how to debug linux kernel at startup ?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK in kernel config. (make menuconfig -> Kernel Hacking -> Early printk)
https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing#Pros_and_Cons